# Android/ JavaScript - Passing data within a URL

Tags: javascript, android, redirect, cordova

I am passing a value through a url in my android phonegap app using the below:

```
window.location.href = "results.html?score="+encodeURIComponent(myvalue);
```

However, when the phone/ simulators firmware is updated to 4.03, this no longer seems to work. Could someone please advice further.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Your edits change the question pretty markedly.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, sorry for not being clear earlier, was my mistake accidently added " within the code snippet. The myvalue is essentially an integer which is being taken from a textbox.

Comment: another thing to bear in mind is the fact that the above code only stopped working in 4.03! Thanks

Comment: I can't see any problem with the above in any even marginally compliant web browser. Are you quite sure the problem isn't elsewhere? In any case, good luck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug on Android. You should go star it:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

In the meantime use localStorage.setItem()/getItem() to pass values between pages.

Comment: Do you know id there are a lot of Web View bugs with android 4.03, as another bug I am experiancing is my app is not loading up for the first ever time. But it is fine after that? Thanks

Comment: Um no, I haven't heard of that. You should grab the "adb logcat" and go ask your question on the PhoneGap Google Group.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that middle "..use this...window.location.href = "results.html?score=1.56"

Comment: My mistake there I accidently added a " within my code snippet was actually correct in the first place, please see the edited question. Thanks